# problem in installing mysql

Tags: command-line

```
sandeep@sandeep-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 0):

Often, I'll have Synaptic package manager open or something similar. This puts a lock doing installations solely for Synaptic.

Take a look at what else may be running on the system ...

Comment: It's just a permission error here (they're running it without sudo)